# Creating New Folder on Desktop

Tags: windows-7

When I try to create a new folder on desktop with a particular name or title, and I press enter, it notifies me that the destination already contains the folder with that name, and do I wish to substitute the files? When I say "yes", the folder on the desktop just disappears! So, I am unable to create that folder with that name. Obviously I can just rename the folder to something else, but it bothers me that there is a folder existing somewhere that I now want to eliminate but cannot.

When I go to Start and do research for the file or folder with that name, it is unable to find it or it does not exist. This really bothers me not because I want to create the folder with that particular name, but because something is wrong and should be put right. What can I do to rectify this?

I have to say that recently I had to force windows to go back to a certain update windows point in the past and this I am sure caused the problem.

Answer (score 2):

It is likely that there is a hidden folder located on the desktop;  change your folder options to show hidden folders.

To do so:

1. Open Control Panel
2. Search for "Folder Options"
3. Change to the "View" tab of the Folder Options dialog
4. In the "Hidden files and folders" area, choose "Show hidden files, folders, and drives"

Here is a screenshot of where to find this setting withing Folder Options:

[image]